# Unable to get the div "tags" under the photo, it is auto placed next to the image within the div

Tags: css

How do I go about getting the div "Tags" under the photo, I want a thing like bar tags under it, but I'm unable to get it to go under the photo. I don't want to use absolute because it'll break the page flow; also, when I add Display:block; to the image, It doesn't take up the whole top of the div "pab"

```css
html, body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.text{
  font-family: "Bangers";
  font-size: 5vh;
  color:white;
}

body{
  background:#a89ed2;
}

#topbar{
  background:#483467;
  display:block;
  height:calc(10vh - 1vh);
  border-bottom: 1vh solid #ea5773;
}

#media{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height:9vh;
  padding: 0px 1vw
}

#cord img{
  width:8vh;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:.5vh;
  filter: invert(1);
}

#cord span{
  position:relative; 
  bottom:2vh;
}

#pab{
  display:inline-flex;
  height:50vh;
  width:40vw
}

#pab img{
  height:30vh;
  border:2px solid white;
}

#tags{
  width:40vw;
  height:20vw;
  margin-top:100%;
  margin-left:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id=topbar>
      <div id=media>
        <div id=cord><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-and-brands-3/512/91_Discord_logo_logos-512.png"><span class=text>Salt#7283</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id=pab><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/741394397064855749/742603618481471539/Webp.net-resizeimage_39.png">
      <div id=tags></div>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is not clear which div you want to add under the picture. show a screenshot of the desired result

Comment: Something like this, but I want tags to stay within the div "pab" and be a child. 

https://gyazo.com/59e06bc019b316347dea108ce2f16acc

Comment: Basically, I want the div pab to contain the photo and the tags.

Comment: tags need to be like that bottom div that I placed there, that's where I want the div "tags" which is a child of pab.

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/xszBHGn

Comment: yeah like that, is it a child of the div "pab"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In css I have marked all my edits. Was it necessary?

```css
html, body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.text{
  font-family: "Bangers";
  font-size: 5vh;
  color:white;
}

body{
  background:#a89ed2;
}

#topbar{
  background:#483467;
  display:block;
  height:calc(10vh - 1vh);
  border-bottom: 1vh solid #ea5773;
}

#media{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height:9vh;
  padding: 0px 1vw
}

#cord img{
  width:8vh;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:.5vh;
  filter: invert(1);
}

#cord span{
  position:relative; 
  bottom:2vh;
}

#pab{
  display: inline-flex; /*add*/
  flex-direction: column; /*add*/
  align-items: flex-start; /*add*/
  
  height:50vh;
  width:40vw
}

#pab img{
  height:30vh;
  border:2px solid white;
}

#tags{
  width:40vw;
  height:20vw;
  /*margin-top:100%;*/ /*remove*/
  /*margin-left:100%;*/ /*remove*/
  background-color: aquamarine; /*add*/
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id=topbar>
      <div id=media>
        <div id=cord><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-and-brands-3/512/91_Discord_logo_logos-512.png"><span class=text>Salt#7283</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id=pab><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/741394397064855749/742603618481471539/Webp.net-resizeimage_39.png">
      <div id=tags></div>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, heavily helps; though may I ask you one side question here for future reference, I have a 90 min post timer.

Comment: The question is about the below answer from the guy; if you take his code and input it...how would I go about removing that yellow margin boxing? Because I have a problem with that and I"m trying to learn how to stop it. Do I have to remove the block element of it or what?

Comment: well, he just changed the answer, but how do I go about removing yellow margin boxes when they force the document out of flow?

Comment: what yellow margin are you talking about?

Comment: If you use chrome developer tools, the yellow color is margins, if you hover over some divs (Not in this project) you'll see the margins, which means items can't be placed next to them, how do I go about removing margins, or is that just due to blocks?

Comment: do you mean how do you get rid of margin? if I understand you correctly, then the margin: 0

Comment: Yeah ok, thanks; won't margin 0 move it from where I want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Want something like this....

```css
html, body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.text{
  font-family: "Bangers";
  font-size: 5vh;
  color:white;
}

body{
  background:#a89ed2;
}

#topbar{
  background:#483467;
  display:block;
  height:calc(10vh - 1vh);
  border-bottom: 1vh solid #ea5773;
}

#media{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height:9vh;
  padding: 0px 1vw
}

#cord img{
  width:8vh;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:.5vh;
  filter: invert(1);
}

#cord span{
  position:relative; 
  bottom:2vh;
}

#pab{
  height:50vh;
}

#pab img{
  height:30vh;
  border:2px solid white;
}

#tags{

  
}
#wrapper{
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
  <div id=topbar>
    <div id=media>
      <div id=cord><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-and-brands-3/512/91_Discord_logo_logos-512.png"><span class=text>Salt#7283</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id=pab>
      <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/741394397064855749/742603618481471539/Webp.net-resizeimage_39.png">
      <div id=tags>Tag Here</div>
    </div> 
    <div>
      Other Contents here
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Will I still be able to add content next to the div pab, like if I make a new div called "content" can I like put it next to pab and have stuff appear next to pab, without breaking the flow of the document?